# Event Click Button for Service

Tags: javascript, typescript, button, routes, click

I set the path in touting:

{
path:'home',
conponent:homecompnent;
}

app.component.html:
<button(click)="routerLink=/home"

This is an error

Want to go to the home page while clicking?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it
**app.component**

```html
<button (click)="goToHome('home')"/>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private router:Router){}

GOToHome(_pageName:string):void{
          this.router.navigate[`${_pageName}'];
```

**app-routing**

```
{path:'home',
  component:homecomponent
},
```